# bind 'this' to a imported function vanilla js

Tags: javascript

```
function PersonListView() {
this._html = html;
/../
}

PersonListView.prototype = {
    addPersonHandler: function (handler) {
        addList().bind(this);
        
}

function addList() {
    let elList = this._mHtml.querySelector('#todo');
    if (elList)
        elList.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var todo = document.getElementById("todo").value;
            document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")[0].value = "";
            handler(todo);
        });
}
```

i want to ask how can i bind 'this' to addList so i dont have to pass this in the parameter of the functions, i don't know what i do wrong

Comment: `addList().bind(this);` <= remove the `()`.  And actually how you are using it, you don't need bind.  You can do just `addList.call(this)`

Comment: if i want to move the function to another file i still can use call?

Comment: Why distinguish between `addPersonHandler` and `addList` at all? Also, what's happening to the `handler` parameter? And do you have mismatched parenthesis in your actual code as well?

Comment: The logic existing in another file or not is not an issue, at least concerning the choice between `call()` and `bind()`.  In both cases, you would need some element you are wanting to define as the `this`.  If you do not have that element, then you have a different issue than what this question asks about

Comment: well i remove a large area of the code the  addPersonHandler have alot of buttons inside it so i decided to take every button and is eventlisner and move it to another file so its will be much smaller file, also the handler is insde the code

i just remove the unnecessary code so it will be easier to show you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you actually *don't* want to bind the function to anything. You can just make it become the method directly:

```
/* file A */
export function addList(handler) {
    let elList = this._mHtml.querySelector('#todo');
    if (elList)
        elList.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var todo = document.getElementById("todo").value;
            document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")[0].value = "";
            handler(todo);
        });
    }
}
```

```
/* file B */
import { addList } from '…';

…
PersonListView.prototype = {
    addPersonHandler: addList,
};
```

(I would however advise against scattering the methods of a single class over multiple files)

Comment: well i just gonna use one file for is long method so the code will look better

Comment: No, the actual problem there seems to be that the method is too long. Refactor it into multiple smaller methods or helper functions. Or use loops and data structures to remove duplicate code.